# A semicolon or a comma in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

I am stuck between the use of a comma or semicolon here. I think a comma is a better choice to place after "respectively", simply because the next sentence is not a full sentence and sounds more like a clause than a sentence.

> Model thickness and tamper area were considered as 5 m and 4 m<sup>2</sup>, respectively, the same as those which have been previously used in verification process by experimental data of Oshima and Takada.

Answer (score 2):

The clauses set off by semicolons should each be a grammatical sentence in its own right.  Consider:

> The same as those which have been previously used in verification process by experimental data of Oshima and Takada.

That's not a sentence, just a complicated noun phrase.  Hence, no semicolon.

Comment: Not necessarily, although in this case yes.  A semi-colon can also be used to delimit items in a list that themselves contain commas: "Alice travelled with Bob, a banker; Carl, a chef; and Denise, her dentist."  Alice travelled with 3 people, not 6.